# How to pass this module's data into index.ejs with Express?

Tags: express, npm, ejs

Stuck on my first very basic app. The 'heavy lifting' works: the scrape.scrape(); function imports a module, which  returns an array of strings (by scraping an external site).

When I run 'node index.js', I see the array being returned in terminal, and when I  open localhost:3000 it just 'hello world'. But if I open devtools on this localhost index page, there's nothing being logged in console.

index.js

```
var scrape = require('./src/scraper');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

scrape.scrape();     
// returns ['headline one','headline two', etc...]. Trying to pass this data to index.ejs 


app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs');
});
```

/views/index.ejs

```
<body>hello world</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> your controller here index.js

```
var array = scrape.scrape(); //pass this array in res.render 

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs', {data : array});//your data is render through view
});
```

> your ui here index.ejs

```
<body>hello world</body>
<h1><%= data[0] %></h1> //your data will render here
```

[official ejs documentation here](http://www.embeddedjs.com/)
hope this helps you